# How to save exit nvim in git bash commit

Tags: vim, git-bash, neovim

I'm using git bash on Win 10 and nvim as the editor. When I commit with no message it opens a blank screen (where blank means BLANK, not mostly blank with a line number at the bottom), I type "stuff", I <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> but "wq" is inserted. I <C-c> and get the obligatory you're-an-idiot-and-didn't-give-a-commit-message error. I start nvim directly and get the same blank screen and the same effect of only the first character of any command after <Esc> is not inserted then we go right back to insert mode so <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> acts like <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> ... totally at a loss. Is git bash incompatible with nvim?

Edit: In case a visual helps
[image]

Comment: interesting. Just curious, How did you create this visual ?

Comment: @VenkataramanR ScreenToGif  ..  https://www.screentogif.com/

Comment: Thanks for the information. It is very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [neovim/neovim issue 9585](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/9585) illustrates that nvim can be used with Git.

Check  with a `git config core.editor` *how* nvim was declared as Git editor.

It can be:

```
git config --global core.editor '"nvim -u NORC"'
```

On Windows, [this issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/9405#issuecomment-493770875) suggests:

```
git config --global core.editor "set LC_CTYPE='en_US.UTF-8';nvim"
```

Using [`mhinz/neovim-remote`](https://github.com/mhinz/neovim-remote) can help:

git config --global core.editor 'nvr --remote-wait-silent'

Comment: Makes sense. I did `git config --global core.editor "nvim"`

Comment: @Still.Tony You mean the `core.editor` setting was not set before?

Comment: I don't know what it was set to before. Come to think of it, I had the same problem before I set it and that's why I set it. I didn't think to check first; just assumed it was wrong.   This is all on a fresh win10 azure vm

Comment: I tried the first two suggestions and neither worked. I did not try neovim-remote. I have to tediously verify anything I install on this vm for security. I upvoted because it seems reasonable but I'll wait for someone else to test or till I can test it on a non-critical system before accepting.

Comment: @Still.Tony No problem. Let me know of what will work in your case.

Comment: I was having the same problem. The NORC solution works for me, but the LC_CTYPE one didn't. So with that, I'm assuming there is something messed up in my rc file.

Comment: @RichardO'Neil Indeed. I would simplify that rc file content, before restoriing said content, to see if and what might cause the problem to persists.

Comment: @VonC I ran with your suggestion and it looks like it is vim-airline that is causing the issue. At least I know where to look now. Thanks.